# Enforce Schema-bound views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

For reporting purposes, I need to be able to query dependencies between views and underlying tables at column level (via `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`).

One way to get SQL Server to store referenced columns is to use schemabound views. As some of my users will create views too, I would like to enforce those. As far as I've seen it isn't possible to allow only views with schemabinding to be created within a SQL Server database though (although this seems a legit requirement to me).

Are there other ways to force SQL Server to keep track of which columns are being referenced by which views? Or is there a hidden way to enforce schemabound views in SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a DDL trigger for this. Unfortunately `SCHEMABINDING` is not an attribute in the `EVENTDATA` structure, so you have to construct the object name and check a property using that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER EnforceViewBinding
ON DATABASE 
FOR CREATE_VIEW, ALTER_VIEW 
AS
    DECLARE @xml xml = EVENTDATA();
    DECLARE
        @Name sysname =
            QUOTENAME(@xml.value('(./EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname')) + 
            N'.' +
            QUOTENAME(@xml.value('(./EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname'));

    IF OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID(@Name, N'V'), 'IsSchemaBound') = 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Views must specify the WITH SCHEMABINDING option.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
```

Answer (score 7):

Very easy to do with a DDL trigger on your database:

```
CREATE TRIGGER RequireSchemaBinding ON DATABASE FOR CREATE_VIEW, ALTER_VIEW
AS
DECLARE @object nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @schema nvarchar(max)
SET @object = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
SET @schema = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
IF ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@object)), 'IsSchemaBound'), 0) = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Not today, punk.', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method would be to use a policy.  I created a sample policy using the following script generated by SSMS and it worked.

```
Declare @object_set_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_object_set @object_set_name=N'SchemaBinding_Required_ObjectSet', @facet=N'IViewOptions', @object_set_id=@object_set_id OUTPUT
Select @object_set_id

Declare @target_set_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'SchemaBinding_Required_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/View', @type=N'VIEW', @enabled=True, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/View', @level_name=N'View', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
GO

Declare @policy_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_policy @name=N'SchemaBinding_Required', @condition_name=N'SchemaBound_Required', @policy_category=N'', @description=N'', @help_text=N'', @help_link=N'', @schedule_uid=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', @execution_mode=1, @is_enabled=True, @policy_id=@policy_id OUTPUT, @root_condition_name=N'', @object_set=N'SchemaBinding_Required_ObjectSet'
Select @policy_id
GO
```

Of course my understanding is that it is enforced by using triggers anyway but it may be easier to manage doing it this way.  Also if you have multiple instances you can use a CMS (Central Management Server) to enforce the policy across all or some of your instances.